# Aggregate series from DataFrame based on specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data structure:

```
       sls   srx    stx  hostname    m                          @timestamp
0        1  21.1  389.2         A  dev 2021-03-05 05:00:00.112965476+00:00
1        0  0.0   352.4         A  dev 2021-03-05 05:00:00.263778044+00:00
2        0  0.0   351.5         A  dev 2021-03-05 05:00:00.463778044+00:00
3        0  0.0   333.6         A  dev 2021-03-05 05:00:00.663778044+00:00
4        1  13.8  379.1         A  dev 2021-03-05 05:00:00.811431112+00:00
5        1  14.6  369.2         A  dev 2021-03-05 05:00:01.011431112+00:00
6        1  15.4  359.3         A  dev 2021-03-05 05:00:01.211431112+00:00
7        0  0.0   371.5         A  dev 2021-03-05 05:00:01.459895995+00:00
8        1  64.1  353.8         A  dev 2021-03-05 05:00:01.608929154+00:00
```

And I'm trying to compute a dataframe or series that looks like this:

```
                                  start                                   end                duration
0   2021-03-05 05:00:00.263778044+00:00 2021-03-05 05:00:00.811431112+00:00 0 days 00:00:00.547653068
1   2021-03-05 05:00:01.459895995+00:00 2021-03-05 05:00:01.608929154+00:00 0 days 00:00:00.149033159
```

So that I can compute the following things:

1. Count of `0` to `1` transitions (including `0, 0, 0, 0, 1` sequences) - e.g. `2` for the above data
2. Total duration of these `0` to `1` transitions - e.g. `0.696686227` for the above data

So the query is looking for the first row where `sls` is `0`, then for the first row that is `1` after that. And it needs to do this for every occurrence of `0` (excluding those that are between a `0` and a `1`).

My naive impl. using pandas is:

```py
# @timestamp is a ISO8601 datetime string
df['@timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['@timestamp'])

df['status_change'] = df['sls'].ne(df['sls'].shift())
df = df.drop(df.index[0])

start = df.loc[(df['sls'] == 0) & (
    df['status_change'] == True)].reset_index()
end = df.loc[(df['sls'] == 1) & (
    df['status_change'] == True)].reset_index()

series = pd.DataFrame()
series['start'] = start['@timestamp']
series['end'] = end['@timestamp']
series['duration'] = series['end'] - series['start']
```

But I feel like there must be an easier way of doing this that would also result in better performance (currently, for 4M documents, it takes about `0:01:06.819145` which is not great).

I'm just not sure how else to query the data in the way I described it so that performance is at least 2x better.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you're lookig for `groupby`?
`df.groupby(by=["sls"]).sum()`

group by docs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html